# The fetchSignInMethodsForEmail function always returns an empty array

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, expo

In my expo application, I want to add a function that will check whether the user with the given email address exists and, based on this, redirect him to the appropriate screen - login or registration.

My function:

```
  const checkFirebaseAccount = async () => {
    try {
      const userCredential = await fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(auth, email);

      if (userCredential.length > 0) {
        console.log("User exists", userCredential);
      } else {
        console.log("User does not exist", userCredential);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error: ", error.message);
    }
  };
```

Unfortunately, every time I call the function by providing the email address for which the account exists in my Firebase Auth, the console shows LOG User does not exist []

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You have to configure your project to allow this (understanding that this is a potential security or privacy problem).  See the duplicate for details. In the future, consider [doing a web search](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/search-and-study) before posting a question.